# Admob does not show ads in android

Tags: android, admob

I don't know why, but Admob does not show my ads, but my application runs perfectly.

Here is my activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Log.d("GameActivity", "started");

      context = this.getApplicationContext();

      Uri game = this.getIntent().getData();
      if (game != null) {
        if (game.getScheme().equals ("file")) {
          gamePath = game.getPath();
        } else {
          copyGameToCache (game);
        }
        Log.d("GameActivity", "Selected the file: " + getGamePath());
      }

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


      adView = new AdView(mSingleton);
      adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER); 
      adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1209995634500922/8885931497");


      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      mLayout.addView(adView, params);
    }
```

And this is my androidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="org.love2d.android"
      android:versionCode="14"
      android:versionName="0.9.1b"
      android:installLocation="auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Allow writing to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="Application"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
      <service android:name=".DownloadService" />
      <activity
        android:name="GameActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="Application"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <category android:name="tv.ouya.intent.category.GAME"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:scheme="file" />
          <data android:scheme="content" />
          <data android:mimeType="application/x-love-game" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:scheme="file" />
          <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
          <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.love" />
          <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="DownloadActivity" 
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPrefix="*"
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.love" />
          <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPrefix="*"
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.love" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 

    </application>

    <!-- Android 2.3.3 -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" /> 
</manifest>
```

My application starts without any errors, I can use it perfectly but it does not show the ad.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: see the log cat if it is showing some warnings..

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951106/admob-ad-not-showing-up-in-emulator-or-phone has some useful information in it? I'm not too familiar with admob myself.

Comment: My logcat displays this error:
http://pastebin.com/qkppiiY3

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to put a test device, something like this:

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] digest = md5.digest(android_id.getBytes());
String deviceId = Base64.encodeToString(digest, 0);

AdRequest adRequest = new dRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("17BB429573B0FA8677D27957B98C7005").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```